pde with special boundary condition
https://www.phys.ens.fr/~ebrunet/Papers/BrunetDerrida.15.pdf
I found   in  this aricle of  Éric Brunet and Bernard Derrida "AnExactly Solvable Travelling Wave Equation", the following :
the authors Consider the following linearized Fisher-KPP equation with a given time-dependent boundary $X_t$ with $X_0=0$ :
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+f^{\prime}(0) u \quad \text { if } x>X_t, \\
u\left(X_t, t\right)=0 .
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}
$$
For a given $y>0$, we look at the value $u\left(X_t+y, t\right)$ of the solution at a distance $y$ from the boundary. Intuitively, if $X_t$ increases too quickly with $t$, this quantity is pushed to zero. On the other hand, if $X_t$ increases too slowly, it diverges with $t$. It is only for finely tuned choices of $X_t$ that $u\left(X_t+y, t\right)$ remains of order 1 .
Now we suppose that $X_t$ is no longer given a priori but is instead determined by
$$
u\left(X_t+1, t\right)=1 \tag{2}
$$
For initial conditions decaying fast enough, one expects $X_t$ to be asymptotically linear. If $X_t$ were really linear (not only asymptotically but at all times), (88)(which is the above eqaution) would be very easy to solve.
The version we actually consider is therefore the following: For each given time $t$, we replace the boundary by a linear boundary of slope $X_t / t$ and solve
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+f^{\prime}(0) u \quad \text { if } x>\frac{X_t}{t} s, \\
u\left(\frac{X_t}{t} s, s\right)=0 .
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}
$$
We then tune the value of $X_t$ to satisfy (2) at time $t$.
For an initial condition $\delta\left(x-x_0\right)$ the solution to (3) is
$$
g\left(x, s \mid x_0\right)=\frac{e^{f^{\prime}(0) s}}{\sqrt{4 \pi s}}\left[\exp \left(-\frac{\left(x-x_0\right)^2}{4 s}\right)-\exp \left(\frac{X_t}{t} x_0-\frac{\left(x+x_0\right)^2}{4 s}\right)\right]
$$
I have  question: how do we get this solution because when I use usual heat kernel for the quation when x in <hole space  I get the  first term :$$\frac{e^{f^{\prime}(0) s}}{\sqrt{4 \pi s}}\exp \left(-\frac{\left(x-x_0\right)^2}{4 s}\right)$$
here what i do : the answer is :since the Dirichlet problem for the heat equation
$$
u_s=k u_{x x}, \quad u(x, 0)=\varphi(x), \quad u(0, s)=0
$$
on the half line $x>0$. To solve this problem, one extends $\varphi$ to the whole real line in such a way that the extension is odd and then solves the corresponding problem to get
$$
u(x, t)=\int_0^{\infty}[S(x-y, t)-S(x+y, t)] \cdot \varphi(y) d y .
$$
then put $v(x,s)=u(x,s)\exp(-\frac{X_t}{t}x_0)$ and then $y=x-\frac{X_t}{t}s$note that t here is a parameter
so my proof is it true ?

Can you put the domains of the variables? It is not clear whether $t$ is a constant or not. Also, I wouldn't call the solution given a traveling wave as it doesn't seem to translate as $s\to\infty$. Please improve the quality of the question.

No, $g(x,s|x_0)$ does not mean that $s=x_0$. It means that the solution $g$ is a function of the variables $x$ and $s$, and of the parameter $x_0$.

If you have the article link, please share with us.

@UserA no its not travelling waves but the authors use this equation to describe behaviour and convergence of fisher kpp solution

@Gonçalo ,see my edit , i suggested an answer , tell me please  what do you think about it,if you dont agree caan you tell me why ?

the answer is :since the Dirichlet problem for the heat equation
$$
u_t=k u_{x x}, \quad u(x, 0)=\varphi(x), \quad u(0, t)=0
$$
on the half line $x>0$. To solve this problem, one extends $\varphi$ to the whole real line in such a way that the extension is odd and then solves the corresponding problem to get
$$
u(x, t)=\int_0^{\infty}[S(x-y, t)-S(x+y, t)] \cdot \varphi(y) d y .
$$
then put $v(x,s)=u(x,s)\exp(-\frac{X_t}{t}x_0)$ and then $y=x-\frac{X_t}{t}x_0$
